# assetsディレクトリ内のファイルをMediaPlayerで再生するには？

Tags: android

AndroidのMediaPlayerクラスで`assets`ディレクトリ内にある動画ファイルを再生したいのですが、どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`setDataSource`に`FileDescriptor`で指定すると再生できると思います。

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor fd = getAssets().openFd("video.mp4");
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();
```